# Elastic Search Geo Spatial search implementation

Tags: elasticsearch, geospatial, elastic-stack, inverted-index

I am trying to understand how elastic search supports Geo Spatial search internally.

For the basic search, it uses the inverted index; but how does it combine with the additional search criteria like searching for a particular text within a certain radius.

I would like to understand the internals of how the index would be stored and queried to support these queries

Comment: What do you mean by "searching for a particular text within a certain radius"?

Comment: Lets say you are searching for a keyword "Pizza" and you are expecting to find a list of Places (restaurants etc) nearby that match your keyword

Comment: @java_geek did you find the answer else where? If so please can you share here?!

Answer (score 0):

Text & geo queries are executed separately of one another. Let's take a concrete example:

```json
PUT restaurants
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "location": {
        "type": "geo_point"
      },
      "menu": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST restaurants/_doc
{
  "name": "rest1",
  "location": {
    "lat": 40.739812,
    "lon": -74.006201
  },
  "menu": [
    "european",
    "french",
    "pizza"
  ]
}

POST restaurants/_doc
{
  "name": "rest2",
  "location": {
    "lat": 40.7403963,
    "lon": -73.9950026
  },
  "menu": [
    "pizza",
    "kebab"
  ]
}
```

You'd then `match` a text field and apply a `geo_distance` filter:

```json
GET restaurants/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "menu": "pizza"
          }
        },
        {
          "geo_distance": {
            "distance": "0.5mi",
            "location": {
              "lat": 40.7388,
              "lon": -73.9982
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "function_score": {
            "query": {
              "match_all": {}
            },
            "boost_mode": "avg",
            "functions": [
              {
                "gauss": {
                  "location": {
                    "origin": {
                      "lat": 40.7388,
                      "lon": -73.9982
                    },
                    "scale": "0.5mi"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Since the `geo_distance` query only assigns a boolean value (--> score=1; only checking if the location is within a given radius), you may want to apply a gaussian `function_score` to boost the locations that are closer to a given origin.

Finally, these scores are overridable by using a `_geo_distance` sort where you'd order by the proximity (while of course keeping the `match` query intact):

```json
...
  "query: {...},
  "sort": [
    {
      "_geo_distance": {
        "location": {
          "lat": 40.7388,
          "lon": -73.9982
        },
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I wanted to understand how the geo_distance works internally. Normally if its just text search, it works on top of the inverted index; but with the geo_distance filter included, what additional data strcutures would be required to handle such a query