# Unable to find source.geo.location elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to convert the following to a geo_point type:

```
               "location": {
                  "properties": {
                    "lat": {
                      "type": "float"
                    },
                    "lon": {
                      "type": "float"
                    }
                  }
                }
```

The issue that I am running into is that the field source.geo.location is not of type geo_point. I would like to modify the location mapping to look like this:

```
                 "location": {
                  "type": "geo_point"
                  "properties": {
                    "lat": {
                      "type": "float"
                    },
                    "lon": {
                      "type": "float"
                    }
                  }
```

Here is a picture of the problem shown on the geo visualization:

[image]

Someone has ran into a similar issue: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-construct-geo-point-field-from-separate-fields-of-latitude-and-longitude-for-kibana-5-4/91755. This doesn't really help me because I need to update an existing index. Can this be done?

Comment: Once you defined geo_point type, there is no nide for lat  lng.and

Answer (score 0):

Once you've set the `geo_point` mapping, you won't need the two `float` data types.

In essence, you'd need to drop your index, correctly define the mapping, and then reindex your data. There's no other way because converting from a dictionary of floats to a geo point is considered a "mapping breaking change."

Maybe my answer to [Elastic Search Geo Spatial search implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61853684/elastic-search-geo-spatial-search-implementation/61859147#61859147) would help you get started.